# How to start a GUI software on a remote Linux server via SSH?

Tags: linux, matlab, shell, ssh, server

I am trying to open Matlab software installed in remote Linux server from my Windows 7 PC. I am using SSH secure shell to connect with the Linux server. After successful connection, I am able to see and access the folders under my user account. I am able to start Matlab software using the following command in the SSH secure shell window:

[sushma@scorpio home]$ matlab

On doing so the following message gets displayed on the SSH secure shell window:

MATLAB is selecting SOFTWARE OPENGL rendering.
No protocol specified

```
                               < M A T L A B (R) >
                     Copyright 1984-2015 The MathWorks, Inc.
                     R2015b (8.6.0.267246) 64-bit (glnxa64)
                                 August 20, 2015
```

From the above message it seems that the software is running. I want to access the GUI of the software.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to `ssh -X`

From ssh manual:

> -X      Enables X11 forwarding.  This can also be specified on a per-host basis in a configuration file.
>
> X11 forwarding should be enabled with caution.  Users with the ability to bypass file permissions on the remote host (for
>   the user's X authorization database) can access the local X11 display
>                through the forwarded connection.  An attacker may then be able to perform activities such as keystroke monitoring.
>
> For this reason, X11 forwarding is subjected to X11 SECURITY extension restrictions by default.  Please refer to the ssh
>   -Y option and the ForwardX11Trusted directive in ssh_config(5) for more
>                information.
>
> -Y      Enables trusted X11 forwarding.  Trusted X11 forwardings are not subjected to the X11 SECURITY extension controls.

Comment: You'll also need an X server on the Windows machine. Cygwin provides one that worked last time I used it. This page has more info: http://xfree86.cygwin.com/docs/ug/using-remote-apps.html

Comment: not working. still not able to access the GUI of the sofftware

Comment: Instructions after installing Cygwin are needed. I am pretty new to this and don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

steps that worked for me:

1. connect to the server by using the ssh `-X` flag
2. execute Matlab with `matlab &` (you should see Matlab opening on your local machine)
3. check within Matlab with the command `opengl info` if either software or hardware opengl is being used (if you're having trouble loading opengl go to step 2 and execute `matlab -softwareopengl &`)
4. run your gui script with `run <script>`

If the script is supposed to run independent of your ssh connection, I suggest to use the program `tmux` and repeat step 2-4 inside a tmux session